# Difference between this grammar

Tags: automata, finite-automata, cellular-automata

I was reading a book and there is a part in which they use this grammar
$$
X \rightarrow xY $$
$$
Y \rightarrow yZ
$$
$$ Z \rightarrow z$$
$$ Z \rightarrow \lambda $$

and other times they use this other one
$$ X \rightarrow xyz $$
$$ X \rightarrow x $$

It mentions that both are equivalent but I don't understand why it is preferable to use the first grammar than the second grammar.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume a variant of your example, one that indeed has a pair of equivalent grammars.

$X\to x \mid  xyz$

$X\to x Y \hspace{1cm} Y\to yz \mid \varepsilon$

Here the second grammar is preferable to the first one in the context of parsing. It is obtained by a process called [left factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_factoring), which is one of the tricks to make a grammar [LL(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar).

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. Consider the string `xy`.
With the first grammar, the string can be generated.

$$
X \rightarrow xY \rightarrow xyZ \rightarrow xy
$$
However, with the second grammar, it cannot be generated given the two rules.

Comment: Maybe the book has a typo, and $Z \rightarrow \lambda$ should really be $Y \rightarrow \lambda$?